# UIImagePickerController crashes in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery

```
-(IBAction)selectPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

I am testing this code on iPad and iPhone simulators. In the iPhone simulator (and on real iPhones too) it's ok - gallery appears. But on the iPad simulator (I don't have a device), it crashes. Any ideas why?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9019460/78336

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please read the exception messages in the device log:

`On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController`

Comment: The documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html states that "On iPad, you can *alternatively* present the user interface using a popover" (following the standard way of using a modal view controller). Thus, according to the documentation, the error message is simply a bug in `UIKit`.

Comment: iOS7 now allows full screen modal presentation of the UIImagePickerController, I haven't tried FormSheet et al but that should be the same!

Answer (score 7):

Max said:

> On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController

It now appears that we can presentModalViewController the UIImagePickerController when its sourceType is set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.  This must be to support the iPad 2's cameras in a full screen view.  Max is correct that presentModalViewController crashes on iPads when sourceType is set to anything else.

Comment: Since when? Which iOS version?

Comment: i am finding the opposite to be true for my iPad2. camera crashes. photo library works.

Answer (score 2):

When displaying a modal view controller on the iPad, that view controller also needs it's `modalPresentationStyle` property to be set in order to display the incoming view.

Here are the options available to you from the documentation:

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalPresentationFullScreen = 0,
   UIModalPresentationPageSheet,
   UIModalPresentationFormSheet,
   UIModalPresentationCurrentContext,
} UIModalPresentationStyle;
```

Comment: I tried to set 
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
or
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
but it doesnt help

Comment: See the answer by @Max. I wasn't aware of this specific requirement for UIImagePickerController on iPad.

Answer (score 2):

try using this code for ipad photolibrary,

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) 
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                       animated:YES];
```

or 
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_(Xcode_4)  reference..