# UIImagePickerController crashes app on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I've made an iPhone app that works perfectly on all iPhone versions I want to support.  My app uses `UIImagePickerController` which again, works fine on iPhone. However, for some reason when I run my app on an iPad (because apple requires this) the app crashes when either of the below methods are called.

```
- (IBAction) useCamera:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = YES;
    }
    if (showingHelp) {
        help1.hidden=YES;
        if (help5.hidden==YES) {
            help2.hidden=NO;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction) useCameraRoll:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

        imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = NO;
    }

}
```

**The app crashes in the @autoreleasepool as below:**

[image]

*Deployment Info:*
[image]
What am I doing wrong here?

*Below is the crash report from Apple:*

```
{"bundleID":"DoDSoftware.My-App-Name","app_name":"My App Name","bug_type":"109","name":"My App Name","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.1 (11D201)","version":"1.0 (1.0)"}
Incident Identifier: 1C3085B5-5239-4157-BEC1-D2E80875E919
CrashReporter Key:   4304b46bdde0982b1769f74dc91e51e1b805ca7d
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             My App Name [933]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/0584F788-3FC7-4D75-AADB-FCA4AA4C0BEC/My App Name.app/My App Name
Identifier:          DoDSoftware.My-App-Name
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-05-09 16:54:41.316 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x182e4ef50 0x18f82c1fc 0x182e4ee90 0x185e8e81c 0x185e96880 0x185e96820 0x185e958ec 0x185e12930 0x185e12690 0x185e11ebc 0x185e11cb8 0x185e204b4 0x185ed9ae8 0x185ed98c4 0x185ed0000 0x185ecfd24 0x185ecfca4 0x185e12ff8 0x185a04258 0x1859fee20 0x1859fecd8 0x1859fe560 0x1859fe304 0x1859f7c38 0x182e0f6a8 0x182e0c930 0x182e0ccbc 0x182d4dc20 0x1889edc0c 0x185e7efdc 0x100044744 0x18fe1faa0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff1a58c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018feae804 abort + 108
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f0d4990 abort_message + 84
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f0f1c28 default_terminate_handler() + 296
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018f82c4d0 _objc_terminate() + 124
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f0ef164 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018f0eea7c __cxa_throw + 132
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018f82c314 objc_exception_throw + 340
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182e4ee8c +[NSException raise:format:] + 124
9   UIKit                           0x0000000185e8e818 -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 552
10  UIKit                           0x0000000185e9687c -[UIViewController __withSupportedInterfaceOrientation:apply:] + 32
11  UIKit                           0x0000000185e9681c -[UIViewController setInterfaceOrientation:] + 144
12  UIKit                           0x0000000185e958e8 -[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 828
13  UIKit                           0x0000000185e1292c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1352
14  UIKit                           0x0000000185e1268c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 680
15  UIKit                           0x0000000185e11eb8 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 140
16  UIKit                           0x0000000185e11cb4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 288
17  UIKit                           0x0000000185e204b0 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1656
18  UIKit                           0x0000000185ed9ae4 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 536
19  UIKit                           0x0000000185ed98c0 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 32
20  UIKit                           0x0000000185ecfffc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 632
21  UIKit                           0x0000000185ecfd20 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 52
22  UIKit                           0x0000000185ecfca0 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 196
23  UIKit                           0x0000000185e12ff4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 344
24  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185a04254 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 180
25  QuartzCore                      0x00000001859fee1c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 296
26  QuartzCore                      0x00000001859fecd4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
27  QuartzCore                      0x00000001859fe55c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
28  QuartzCore                      0x00000001859fe300 CA::Transaction::commit() + 420
29  QuartzCore                      0x00000001859f7c34 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182e0f6a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
31  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182e0c92c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182e0ccb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
33  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182d4dc1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
34  GraphicsServices                0x00000001889edc08 GSEventRunModal + 164
35  UIKit                           0x0000000185e7efd8 UIApplicationMain + 1152
36  My App Name                     0x0000000100044740 0x100034000 + 67392
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018fe1fa9c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff01aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018fe05998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff1ae74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ff99548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff1ae74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ff99548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ff1ae74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ff99548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fdc7908
    x4: 0x0000000000002060   x5: 0x000000016fdc79c0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000640
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000092d676f7  x11: 0x0000000000000300
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x000000018fec7dcb
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00175a9d0123a7b0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000192d7a2a0  x21: 0x00000001701266d8  x22: 0x0000000170126700  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x000000016fdc9158  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000190a73000
   x28: 0x00000001864e7f08  fp: 0x000000016fdc7940   lr: 0x000000018ff9d16c
    sp: 0x000000016fdc7920   pc: 0x000000018ff1a58c cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100034000 - 0x10004bffb My App Name arm64  <e55e77edb8563d51b6b1944f45deea10> /var/mobile/Applications/0584F788-3FC7-4D75-AADB-FCA4AA4C0BEC/My App Name.app/My App Name
0x120018000 - 0x12003cfaa dyld arm64  <628da833271c3f9bb8d44c34060f55e0> /usr/lib/dyld
0x181ab8000 - 0x181bdbff4 AVFoundation arm64  <71b3ba6895883ad3bec5a25d26af998e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x181bdc000 - 0x181c07ff3 libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <b0ce8a8a398a3fad8d58009fdda45a66> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x181c08000 - 0x181c0bfff Accelerate arm64  <fe3a369c06d23c4fb0c053964eab7e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x181c18000 - 0x181debff2 vImage arm64  <35138843dfb73924908202512ca0e178> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x181dec000 - 0x181e8bff7 libBLAS.dylib arm64  <d1836bd233333aadb94d6f848f22251e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x181e8c000 - 0x1821efff6 libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <8c24faa666963e4d905cd73fef3b7324> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1821f0000 - 0x182247fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f9b2f7b3ea2938bf99adbdf9e4cc159c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x182248000 - 0x182267ff7 libvMisc.dylib arm64  <bd7cb5c078cf3d7bba947c31f3d802ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x182268000 - 0x18226bfff vecLib arm64  <c29a5c80dbf73db7b35ea6912c01192a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x18226c000 - 0x182293fff Accounts arm64  <04e6c9c23f373940997e5568b8a52603> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x182298000 - 0x182313ffb AddressBook arm64  <35e5cdf723fb38cdb17c46d6dbb19028> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x182314000 - 0x182457fff AddressBookUI arm64  <507a1a1b26a33193b9a31f72c5a51a7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x182458000 - 0x18246bffc AssetsLibrary arm64  <054d2b33a8213bc4860d8b66a510713a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x1825bc000 - 0x182933ffc AudioToolbox arm64  <c6d6e3f3b295323ca7a6f9016df15057> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x182934000 - 0x182a9fff5 CFNetwork arm64  <ff953c5b90ca320a8141e65032f41ed0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x182aa0000 - 0x182b03ff4 CoreAudio arm64  <027099a00e6f364ea18557d3d7e743c5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x182b04000 - 0x182b1fffb CoreBluetooth arm64  <ca7f04755bc03522b819c19f58a5aa71> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x182b20000 - 0x182d43ffb CoreData arm64  <79836e6d01813ffb9ca5a5723a9ad232> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x182d44000 - 0x182ecffff CoreFoundation arm64  <300ef390e53f36d28f63ca9f105ad86e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x182ed0000 - 0x18302fffb CoreGraphics arm64  <c16c7faf626234f1992f1e7f27ef992f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x183034000 - 0x18307fff8 libCGFreetype.A.dylib arm64  <51d36f0a499838b8a2aa79a5fc9196b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x183084000 - 0x18308fff8 libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <abba57fe12cf30718bb2c460a6380522> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x183284000 - 0x1832a3ff7 libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <a14beaa248403132b59db3788bde7e1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x1832a4000 - 0x18339bffc CoreImage arm64  <2cb108f589ce30e6aa03ebf50787cf8f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x18339c000 - 0x1833f3ff1 CoreLocation arm64  <2837acd3920a36e793f78bb22b194701> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x183430000 - 0x1834c7ff0 CoreMedia arm64  <688c498978a43e1e8a739165c58d9106> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1834c8000 - 0x18357fffb CoreMotion arm64  <8f35199cab473ca1b5d77993101d118c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x183580000 - 0x1835efff7 CoreTelephony arm64  <61e20d91b4d6306881a64da129c0dcf1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1835f0000 - 0x1836abff3 CoreText arm64  <a37c64fd15d7349a80003eb7bd01770d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x1836ac000 - 0x1836c3ffb CoreVideo arm64  <96d0f8afdb8537cca3a45ff7e20f97e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x1838d8000 - 0x183b17ff3 Foundation arm64  <a698ba21ece734889c74bf2c20e6aea4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x183b18000 - 0x183b43ff3 GLKit arm64  <f5444102c89b3b8985506ad8d49149fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit
0x183d48000 - 0x183db7ff3 IOKit arm64  <5bc819eb63983f50a09166eed596c650> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x183db8000 - 0x18401bff9 ImageIO arm64  <dfbd6acd2f3c320882b2adecefe6a168> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x18401c000 - 0x18432fffc JavaScriptCore arm64  <b26f06bcc37f3e9d8a8b4e53bb3fc1dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1843f4000 - 0x1843fbffb MediaAccessibility arm64  <32ba2d484586380cadf7166ba91ffcce> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x1843fc000 - 0x18464bff7 MediaPlayer arm64  <c3c07579c6ef3daa9382d719ea0b3c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x18464c000 - 0x1849e3ff3 MediaToolbox arm64  <bdbcbb17bcff3eceb501876abe1e75f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x184aa8000 - 0x184b23ffd MobileCoreServices arm64  <21036a78054f3e3b8d018be04c3b6bf4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x185798000 - 0x1857a3fff OpenGLES arm64  <1b68409746383b959b144ea4f25c5b06> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x1857a8000 - 0x1857abfff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <9aa52757f8ab359fb944fc4a03f58e3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1857b0000 - 0x1857b7fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <84c6d0e5cda3363c9f3899aafad06708> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x1857b8000 - 0x1857c3ffd libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <a3166c8ff9243db18b2582442204569a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x1857c4000 - 0x18580fff5 libGLImage.dylib arm64  <4ffb900f9bb63098b87f94613cf5a980> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1859f4000 - 0x185b6fff3 QuartzCore arm64  <1ae8ea71790d382e84c3d403f0afaffd> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x185bd4000 - 0x185c2bffb Security arm64  <fb91c2689923333cb17521e27f744a5a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x185c2c000 - 0x185cb7fff Social arm64  <327452a6cdcf3e42a7f71edc0ba0641e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x185d98000 - 0x185dffff7 SystemConfiguration arm64  <58592ccb97af3ceb9008b388c1692d0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x185e04000 - 0x18663bffd UIKit arm64  <434cd368625b376d86dd6c672552efe1> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18663c000 - 0x186697ff3 VideoToolbox arm64  <14549c6db433318e8f8c7935f9249d28> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18691c000 - 0x186943f4d ACTFramework arm64  <31564bc727b53d48b9bd9678a1212f02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ACTFramework.framework/ACTFramework
0x186998000 - 0x1869a3fff AOSNotification arm64  <06d56ecaeb6d304c8da5380956fb9fe7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x186af8000 - 0x186afffff AggregateDictionary arm64  <484f1eccbfff3abc8f349ceee0d1e986> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x186e34000 - 0x186e4bffb AirTraffic arm64  <8243123d62493e72b016c4a36d0a3fab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x187254000 - 0x18729fffb AppSupport arm64  <91a614a788023e73b85bd745d5c54476> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x1872a0000 - 0x1872e3ff8 AppleAccount arm64  <77763dbc6a183d1dac5ec6e1310523c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x1873a8000 - 0x1873bbff9 ApplePushService arm64  <1f8c22c95def39e7b4c708ca33f4e39e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x1873bc000 - 0x1873c7fff AppleSRP arm64  <48092ad0ed5737ceb5796f5dfaf22a34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x1873d0000 - 0x1873dfff8 AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <73e48ef82c3234f996b7debfa7550508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x187438000 - 0x18743ffff BTLEAudioController arm64  <dd06692d2b0f31068579100b13250a0b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x187440000 - 0x18746ffff BackBoardServices arm64  <603da8ec3d06386997bdd080b88ac791> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x187474000 - 0x18747bffd BluetoothManager arm64  <bf587a56cfed380d9c1713997f140ba8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x18747c000 - 0x1874abff7 Bom arm64  <6379746fd0243b96b96af055476df189> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x18756c000 - 0x187577ffc CaptiveNetwork arm64  <2a4c673848483327a270feafa964275b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x187578000 - 0x18768bff2 Celestial arm64  <9b4f78cf2a173c899ec5fbadb2b45823> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x18769c000 - 0x1876a3fff CertUI arm64  <f3fe811f4c913df09844ab7507e9449d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x187788000 - 0x1877abffd ChunkingLibrary arm64  <60b93282ed903919b3d10ed3e47765d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x187808000 - 0x187817ffb CommonUtilities arm64  <087d411b6a1e365f94a7f6fa0bb3cbe7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x187818000 - 0x18781ffff CommunicationsFilter arm64  <ea282f910994391a8fa25ce9043bb9f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x1878c8000 - 0x1878cbff7 ConstantClasses arm64  <fd7267eeb9ba32dd869dd68390c76706> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x187914000 - 0x187917ff7 CoreAUC arm64  <d7fa50b16e3e302fa22d324f245018c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x1879dc000 - 0x187b17fff CoreMediaStream arm64  <1da40a36af2237f0912d337cfe585498> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x187c34000 - 0x187c5bfff CoreServicesInternal arm64  <4c1079995f07394bbe9336272625fa8c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x187c5c000 - 0x187c5fffd CoreSurface arm64  <aa640ef930c436098cb3db9784ed53ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x187d24000 - 0x187d8fff7 CoreUI arm64  <e22b4ced3fa7336ba4a0bdbd50254299> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x187d90000 - 0x187df3ff7 CoreUtils arm64  <ffce9ffce65b3b56950ddec6d9d1ad56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x187df4000 - 0x187dfbffc CrashReporterSupport arm64  <15b85b4c1d603dc99361e3f2ec526f11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x188014000 - 0x18802fffc DataAccessExpress arm64  <8109b0c5a6dc3fda98d9ba3e04270f1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18803c000 - 0x188057fff DataDetectorsCore arm64  <7bb77a5040b53eda97ce0e408b9b8db5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x18805c000 - 0x188077fff DataDetectorsUI arm64  <d7f11098b8da39f5bf922ddabaf8251d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x188078000 - 0x18807ffff DataMigration arm64  <6ec98d0545b335dea779210d39f0bc8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x188088000 - 0x18808bffb DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <92db1f6bd04c349baf4f9c94b2eb16ae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x18808c000 - 0x1880affff DictionaryServices arm64  <56c6785879223040b7b1788116e9af73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x1880d4000 - 0x1880f7ffc EAP8021X arm64  <2e4eeadd88a0393890d1322969162883> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x188100000 - 0x18810fffd ExFAT arm64  <7e5eab0e3fcd3361a8b382b2269d68fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ExFAT.framework/ExFAT
0x188128000 - 0x188157ff7 FTServices arm64  <dc907c275bbb356495a33e6d1016f6f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x188158000 - 0x18857bf2f FaceCore arm64  <501a5e293f8e3566bfbb9151e02aa361> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x1887f0000 - 0x1887fffff GenerationalStorage arm64  <f983bcfbc3f0339abf01a4b5dd19bb67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x188800000 - 0x1889dfff9 GeoServices arm64  <636d5f53f2ca3af098f03a3eaddb6dc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x1889e0000 - 0x1889fbff3 GraphicsServices arm64  <bb095b54f11b3281829a605b14c2bf47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x188aa4000 - 0x188b3fff7 HomeSharing arm64  <c12a94a43d6335afb9de8f9cf0889ce6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x188b40000 - 0x188b4ffff IAP arm64  <1d30c9ff77ae3bbcb0f62ba48a0e5a0b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x188bc0000 - 0x188bfbffb IDS arm64  <74723a2a456038bfa81e4b6086f23bb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x188c78000 - 0x188c8bfff IDSFoundation arm64  <6f72792b3339346b965b5d9a391d276e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x188e28000 - 0x188e8fff7 IMFoundation arm64  <167c1d4781a638e5b126b0761c15d106> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x188e9c000 - 0x188ea7ffa IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <be838dcdd8d6340b8dc8168c8c5843e4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x188ea8000 - 0x188eaffff IOSurface arm64  <c5040f7529e53c86ad6522cd1fdcf498> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x188eb0000 - 0x188f07ffb ImageCapture arm64  <93c8737fa1bb342795d868f3bbc70c77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x188f34000 - 0x188f43ffe Librarian arm64  <7fdd5bdb1dbd3e2b9a7456cef6917ead> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian
0x188f8c000 - 0x188fd3ff9 MMCS arm64  <d48d3299977c3519962eeb55861387eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x188fdc000 - 0x188febffb MailServices arm64  <a7cad1a9589437dbaaeef9857d688ec3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x18902c000 - 0x1890bffff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <26fc33b8fa203b43bbaec76c54934c91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x1890c0000 - 0x1890c3fff Marco arm64  <931f19e978593da9b2b99af47441f532> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x1890c4000 - 0x18914bff8 MediaControlSender arm64  <f7ac4b2318053f57ac398d84df634a18> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x189194000 - 0x1891a3ff8 MediaRemote arm64  <bcf32bb1f6fe3ec6a48fb5a7f151eb21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x1891a4000 - 0x1891c3ffb MediaStream arm64  <175a74d658bc38f99815b2e60f2ff03f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x189338000 - 0x18933bffd MessageSupport arm64  <d091a9d0c6403f94b8c645b17863f604> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x189348000 - 0x189357ff3 MobileAsset arm64  <5651238de98e385f9b8176c423de74b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x189380000 - 0x18938bffc MobileBluetooth arm64  <3eccd483cf093884b379cd303836490b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x1893b0000 - 0x1893b7ffd MobileInstallation arm64  <9aea725e22563ebea49cead378dc2606> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x1893b8000 - 0x1893c7fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <606c0860130635559af58c9978998beb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1893fc000 - 0x1893ffffd MobileSystemServices arm64  <dc63959297fb3886ba9667c0fc3e4637> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x189424000 - 0x189433ffc MobileWiFi arm64  <ad22f9932cfd3e6ba274e20f4faf3d6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
ff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <658ec4d13ebe3bd6ba6384b6e72d2d2b> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
     ........ 
     ........ Rest removed due to char limit
```

Comment: Are you using two separate interfaces for iPad and iPhone or are you just trying to run an iPhone app on the iPad?

Comment: Search "iPad" in this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html  Does that help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5046519/1402846

Comment: Just trying to run the iPhone app on the iPad, looking into displaying with popover now

Comment: You can't use a popover in an iPhone app.

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger. See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: If you're running the iPhone app on the iPad (such that your app's listed as iPhone only in your settings), you shouldn't have to change any of the code for it to work...and definitely can't use a popover.  Are you sure your app is iPhone only?

Comment: @maddy even if that popover is only used when running on an iPhone?

Comment: I am sure it is iPhone only, and there is no conditional code telling my app to do anything different for iPad

Comment: And just to clarify, when you go to Targets > General and look under Deployment Info, only "iPhone" is displayed next to Devices?

Comment: Correct, I added a screenshot above

Comment: `UIPopoverController` can only be used in an iPad app (or the iPad "half" of a Universal app). It's can't be used in an iPhone-only app even when run on an iPad.

Comment: @maddy, ok I get that, I was only trying it because the others suggested it, my code above does not use a popover, that said, any idea why this is crashing? Thank you for the debug link, on that page it says "A SIGABRT always comes with an error message that you can see in Xcode’s Debug Output pane (bottom right corner of the window). " in my case there is no such message or at least doesnt seem to be , See screenshot ofdebug in my question.

Comment: in your breakpoints navigator (left side of XCode) try adding an exception breakpoint (right click below the last bp and add). It should stop at the line where the crash happens

Comment: @Nitin Alabur i've done so, it's still breaking in the autoreleasepool with the same information

Comment: are there no photos on the iPad album? not sure what else can go wrong. (reset, clean build?)

Comment: there are photos, and the same happens if I try to use the camera. I just dont get it,  I wish it would tell me more about whats causing the error

Comment: The only thing I could think of/find out that's possibly related to this issue is that iPad's running iOS7 potentially have a bug which asks for permission to access photos out of sequence.  Even though it's an iPhone app, perhaps the iPad permission sequence is still off...possibly...? Here's a solution to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19017882/2274694

Comment: Just re worked it to check permissions before calling UIImagePickerControlle, no change. Im rebuilding this as auniversal app now to see it it works that way. If so I'll just make it universail (though the app dosent lend itself well to iPad) but if it fixes the problem so be it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't supplied the deployment detail for the iPad.

It looks like it's an issue with your supported orientations.

```
0x0000000185e8e818 -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 552
```

I suspect that you may need to support portrait to use the camera.

Comment: I could kiss you. You are absolutely right. You apparently must support Portrait to use UIImagePickerController on an iPad. Wow, I never would have thought to check that. They could REALY make this more obvious!Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW how did you know `0x0000000185e8e818 -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 552` meant there was a problem here?

Comment: It was a bit of a guess, but I saw that __supportedInterfaces raised the error so it must be an issue with that, and then I thought it was slightly odd that you weren't supporting portrait and put the two together. Have fun.

Comment: Ahh, ok I see, the stack trace is actually backwards. `[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 552` at line number 9 was the last thing to happen before `[NSException raise:format:] + 124` on line 8 man that makes a lot more sense now. Thanks again